# Не отображаются изменения шаблона в Prestashop

Tags: php, html, smarty, prestashop

Не отображаются изменения шаблона в Prestashop, меняю классы и тп. Но, на сайте ничего из этого не отображается. В чем проблема?

Comment: Кэширование на стороне cms/сервера/браузера?

Comment: @br3t, спасибо за коммент. Узнал о smarty cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Smarty комилирует `.tpl` шаблон в обычный пхп-шаблон. Шаблоны обычно хранят в директориях `templates` ([`$templates_dir`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/variable.template.dir.tpl)),  а для компилированных шаблонов обычно выделяют папку `templates_c` ([`$compile_dir`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/variable.compile.dir.tpl)), к которой настривают права на запись.

Далее смарти работает двумя путями. На продакшене обычно всегда используются скомпилированные варианты, кэш которых очищается только вручную при необходимости (обновили шаблоны), при разработке есть параметр [`$compile_check`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/variable.compile.check.tpl), позволяет проверить шаблон на изменение (по дате изменения). Если шаблон был изменен, то смарти компилирует его заново и обновляет кэш. Если не изменялся, то используется из кэша.

Так что в вашем варианте очистка кэша шаблонов решит вопрос, но и при переносе на продакешн сервер не забудьте выключить проверку шаблонов, ибо она серьезно замедляет работу.

В целом можно также и программным путем очистить кэш одного или всех шаблонов сразу. Для этих целей используется [`clearCompiledTemplate()`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.clear.compiled.tpl.tpl).

Если для переноса кода на продашкен сервер вы, к примеру, используете какие-либо инструменты контроля версий кода (svn, git и т.д.), то (если система позволяет) можно настроить какие-нибудь post-update скрипты, которые будет очищать кэш автоматчиески